# I am getting :: System Error 5 has occured , Access Denied while trying to stop/start a Windows service using SQL JOB

Tags: sql-server, service, jobs

I am trying to run a windows service installed on a server using the SQL JOB. But the thing is I don't have access to the Server, but I have access to its SQL Database.

[image]

While I was running the Job, I am getting this below error.

[image]

Can you please let me know what can be done...??

Comment: I assume that you don't have proper permissions

Comment: Any idea how to get those permissions..?? I don't have access to Server. Is there a way to gain those permissions through the SQL Database..?

Comment: Contact administrators to change permissions for user NTAUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE or provide you another user

Comment: @Kostis...Can you please advice what kind of permissions are needed to be changed....

Comment: I think you need an account with administrative privileges on the server...as i can see you try to stop a service

Comment: When @Kostis says "you" he actually means the service account of the SQL Server. In your case it is currently running under NT Auth. Network Service. You can grant admin rights to that account of course, but that will be a major security hole. You may want to run SQL under another account instead. If you run SQL under the domain account, you can control it from the AD as well.

Comment: @ajeh How can I grant admin rights to NT Auth....??

Comment: LMGTFY: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142166/grant-sysadmin-permissions-to-nt-authority-system